# Using same control in both itemtemplate and edititemtemplate in listview

Tags: asp.net, listview

I have a listview where each row contains usercontrol. Usercontrol data remain same for both EditItemTemplate and ItemTemplate mode. Rather that instanciating the same usercontrol twice for both edit and item mode, is there anyway i can use the itemTemplate usercontrol instance in edititemtemplate?

Answer (score 0):

When a row enters edit mode, it does not render the item template,so there isn't a duplicate rendering... so you only have to worry about one instance for that row anyway.

HTH.

Comment: Actually as a part of requirement i need duplicate rendering. when row enter edit mode it intanciate its own usercontrol which is same as the one in itemtemplate. Maintaing viewstate and fetching data is actuaaly impacting the performance and increasing complexity.